# SP 2013: Moving subwebs within a site collection

Tags: 2013, spweb

Just wondering if anyone knows a quick solution for moving SPWebs, they need to be structurally moved (So no managed navigation solution) and they contain an SPWeb hierarchy (Export/import is out of the question too).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Save As template options, if no more sub-site down that. If you have content then check the "include the content " option.

Another option, I saw the below powershell, another interesting option.

```
#Get the Source Site
$web=Get-SpWeb "http://sharepoint.crescent.com/teams/marketing/us/Policies/"
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates=$true
#Set the Target URL
$web.ServerRelativeUrl="/teams/marketing/Policies/"
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates=$false
$web.update
```

Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/02/move-subsite-between-sites-within-sitecollection.html#ixzz3Alqj0Jlk

Comment: Yeah, the save as template won't work, it's an entire subweb hierarchy I need to move, will try that Powershell however, looks interesting

Comment: I got error `Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again."`

Comment: the second $web.AllowUnsafeUpdates=$false should go after the $web.update I think.

Answer (score 0):

With sufficient permissions, you can use the `Content and structure` tool in the Site Collection to move it.

However the [administrator list threshold issue](http://paulryan.com.au/2014/move-site-operation-fails-list-view-threshold-exception/) could occur (as in my case) while looking for an alternative.